# python3で再び一行目に描画

Tags: python, python3

```
##
##
```

こういった模様を

```
######
######
```

このように繰り返し横並びに出力したいのですが

```py
for _ in range(3):
    print("##\n##")
```

では再び一行目に出力されません。
どうすればよいでしょうか？
また、このような出力を変数に格納する処理も教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: "######\n######"を一度に表示したいのではなく、2つずつ増やしたいのですよね? OSは何をお使いですか?

Comment: `from functools import reduce` として、`box = '##\n##'`, `boxes = reduce(lambda a, _: a.replace('\n', box), range(2), box)` という方法もあります。

Comment: コメント欄は回答欄ではないです。

Comment: たくさん教えていただきありがとうございます。!

Comment: OSはどっちもmac windowsどっちも使ってます。

Comment: 申し添えておきますと、描画する模様(`"##\n##"`)が3行以上になると先程の方法では期待する結果が得られません。

Answer (score 1):

ANSIの `CUU` (Cursor UP) を出力してください。

```
import sys
import time

for i in range(3):
    bar = "##" * (i + 1)

    sys.stdout.write(f"{bar}\n")
    sys.stdout.write(f"{bar}\r")
    sys.stdout.write("\033[1A\r")

    time.sleep(1)

sys.stdout.write("\n\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

最近やり取りしたこの記事と同じ内容ですね。
[Powershellで再描画時に画面のちらつきを抑える方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/61677/26370)
ANSI VT100 エスケープシーケンスを使うことで画面上のカーソル移動とか色付けも行うことが出来ます。

Pythonでは[curses](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/howto/curses.html)が使えるでしょう。
ただしWindows用は無いので代わりにUniCursesというのが使えますと書いてあります。

> Windows 版 Python には curses が含まれていません。 [UniCurses](https://pypi.org/project/UniCurses) という名の移植版が利用可能です。Fredrik Lundh の手による the Console module も試してみると良いでしょう。これには curses と同じ API を用いていませんが、カーソル位置指定でのテキスト出力と、マウス、キーボード入力のフルサポートを提供しています。

---

**追記**
その後調べたら UniCurses は 32ビット環境しかサポートしてなさそうなのが判明。
代替で[windows-curses](https://pypi.org/project/windows-curses/)というのがありましたが、今回の質問では関係無いけれど全角文字の使い方が難しかったのでちょっと保留。
元の英語の紹介記事に載っていたモード設定処理を見つけたのでそちらを入れてみました。

```
import platform
import time

# Windows10 1607以後のコマンドプロンプトでのモード設定(それ以前は未サポート?)
# PowerShellならば不要だが、あっても実行できる
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    from ctypes import windll, wintypes, byref
    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11
    ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING = 0x0004
    hOut = windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(wintypes.HANDLE(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE))
    dwMode = wintypes.DWORD()
    result = windll.kernel32.GetConsoleMode(hOut, byref(dwMode))
    dwMode.value |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING
    result = windll.kernel32.SetConsoleMode(hOut, dwMode)

loopcount = 3                                      # ループ回数
lines = 2                                          # 表示行数
cursorback = '\r' + '\x1B[' + str(lines - 1) + 'A' # カーソルを戻すための文字列
for i in range(loopcount):
    line = '##' * (i + 1)      # ここから
    outstr = line
    for _ in range(lines - 1):
        outstr += '\n' + line  # ここまで, 出力文字列を作成して変数に入れる処理

    print(outstr, end='')      # 文字列表示
    time.sleep(1)              # 表示確認のための1秒待ち
    if i >= (loopcount - 1):   # 最後はカーソルを戻さずに終了
        print('\n')
        break

    print(cursorback, end='')  # 次のループのためにカーソルを戻す処理
```

参考：
[Pythonでコンソールに上書きして出力する方法](http://blog.livedoor.jp/pirosoft/archives/8735780.html)
[Pythonが実行されている環境のOSやバージョン情報などを取得](https://note.nkmk.me/python-platform-system-release-version/)

curses関連
[Fails to import pdcurses on windows 64 bit #2](https://github.com/Chiel92/unicurses/issues/2)
[n十年ぶりにcurses使ったらやっぱいいじゃんっていう話](https://qiita.com/floatnflow/items/1710b0bdd529e4e3a28a)
[Pythonで、cursesモジュールを使う](https://torina.top/detail/437/)
[Python、cursesでシンプルなエディタを作る](https://torina.top/detail/439/)

Comment: なるほど！調べてみます！